# How to add view into LinearLayout of Fragment by onClick?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one Fragment,this layout is one Button.

when button is clicked add textview into textview_container.

how to?

myfragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/textview_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
<Button
                android:id="@+id/postbutton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:background="@null"
                android:text="@string/edit"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Myfragment.java

```
public class AlbumListDetailFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    Button postButton
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment  , container, false);
    }
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        initViews();
    }
     private void initViews() {
          button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.postbutton);
          button.setOnClickListner{new View.onClickListener(){
           public void onClick(View v) {
               //make and Textview  into textview_container
           }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: you have to reference the container, create the textview and append it to the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.textview_container);
TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
linearLayout.addView(valueTV);
```