# Programatically add LinearLayout with Text and Image

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a LinearLayout for each item in a varying Array. I need each item to have an image and text horizontally, but for now I am testing with the text.

Keeping in mind this code is in a Fragment.

I think the error is with the getContext() but not to sure.

The code I currently have is:

```
List<PaymentOption> paymentOptions = aTradeItem.getPaymentOptions();

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(ImageUtils.dpToPx(16), ImageUtils.dpToPx(4), ImageUtils.dpToPx(16), ImageUtils.dpToPx(4));

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lineparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ImageUtils.dpToPx(1));
    lineparams.setMargins(0, ImageUtils.dpToPx(4), 0, ImageUtils.dpToPx(4));

    if (paymentOptions != null && paymentOptions.size() > 0) {
      for (PaymentOption t : paymentOptions) {
        LinearLayout paymentOptionLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        paymentOptionLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        paymentOptionLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        TextView heading = new TextView(getContext());
        heading.setText(t.getDescription());
        heading.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_text));
        heading.setLayoutParams(lp);

        paymentOptionLayout.addView(heading);

      }
    }
```

There are no errors, the data just doesnt populate on the screen. I have tried Hardcoding random text in the setText() but with no success.

Thank you

Comment: Do you add the paymentOptionLayout in the layout after that for loop?

Comment: I dont know why i didnt think of this initially but a RecyclerView would be better for this, less overhead. So i am going to look into that rather. Thanks for the question though @Luksprog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not adding your paymentOptionLayout to the layout which is set as your content View. Basically what you're doing is programatically creating the layout, but then doing nothing with it.

By default your activity_main.xml file will come with some type of layout depending on how you setup your code, for example a blank activity's xml file would be

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

However when you create layouts programmatically the way you did, you must append them to the layout which is the parent layout in your XML file.
So I think what you need to do is the following.

```
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout); //getting the view from the xml file. Keep in mind that the id is defiend in the xml file by you
List<PaymentOption> paymentOptions = aTradeItem.getPaymentOptions();

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(ImageUtils.dpToPx(16), ImageUtils.dpToPx(4), ImageUtils.dpToPx(16), ImageUtils.dpToPx(4));

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lineparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ImageUtils.dpToPx(1));
lineparams.setMargins(0, ImageUtils.dpToPx(4), 0, ImageUtils.dpToPx(4));

if (paymentOptions != null && paymentOptions.size() > 0) {
  for (PaymentOption t : paymentOptions) {
    LinearLayout paymentOptionLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    paymentOptionLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    paymentOptionLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView heading = new TextView(getContext());
    heading.setText(t.getDescription());
    heading.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_text));
    heading.setLayoutParams(lp);

    paymentOptionLayout.addView(heading);
    rl.addView(paymentOptionLayout);  //adding the view to the parent view
  }
}
```

Please note that from the looks of your code, you're really just reimplementing listView which is an available layout in android. I think you should take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

`getContext()` is a method of activity class. It returns the context view only for currently running activity.

For Fragment either pass the instance of current activity class via `constructor` or use `getActivity()` method or `this` instead of `getContext()`

See here for help

1. [Using context in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215308/using-context-in-a-fragment)
2. [How to add view into LinearLayout of Fragment by onClick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539359/how-to-add-view-into-linearlayout-of-fragment-by-onclick)

Also add `paymentOptionLayout` to the parent layout view right after `for loop`.